# Astyle code formatting

Tags: c, linux, coding-style, astyle

I'm writing a linux kernel module, and trying to use [astyle](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/) to help me follow the coding standard. It seems to be formatting a `spi_driver` structure incorrectly and I'm wondering if anyone knows why. This is the code before passing to astyle (with the command `astyle --style=linux lightmod.c`):

```
static struct spi_driver light_driver = {
    .driver = {
            .name = "light",
            .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    },
    .probe = light_probe,
    .remove = __devexit_p(light_remove),
};
```

And this is the output:

```
static struct spi_driver light_driver = {
    .driver = {
            .name = "light",
            .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    },
    .probe = light_probe,
             .remove = __devexit_p(light_remove),
               };
```

Why is it indenting `.remove` this way? Does anyone know?

Comment: I took the liberty of adding an `[astyle]` tag and adding a link.  Please verify that I linked to the right thing.  :)

Comment: If your code uses tabs, you might want to replace them for spaces before using astyle. Or maybe there's an option in astyle to let it be aware of tabs.

Comment: my code does use spaces, not tabs; so that isn't it.
also, the link is correct, thank you.

Comment: What version of astyle?  1.24 does a better job, but still not 100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that there is a deep reason for this. Astyle simply seems not be able to handle C99's designated initializers correctly. If you use oldstyle initializers it formats them fine.

Comment: This is still true in 2017.